# VBA simple Range("a").Value2 = Range("b").Value2 suddenly stops working

Tags: vba, version, named-ranges

in the following sub -  that simply copies one named range to another on a different sheet - has always worked. now apparently something changed and it throws an unspecified runtime error

```
Sub prime_current_sim_input()
    
    With Range("varianten_in")
        .Value2 = Range("sim_direktinput_vals").Value2
    End With
End Sub
```

[runtime error 1004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0qWe.png)

In Contrast, the following works fine

```
Sub prime_current_sim_input()
    Sheets("SIM").Select
    Range("$B$3:$GN$3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Varianten").Select
    Range("H3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

i'm at a complete loss as to what might cause this?
ive already checked:

- the first method has worked on my machine before and still works on others
- All other subs, that work in a similar fashion on other named ranges also throw the same error
- I have previous versions of the same file that work just fine
- windows 10, excel 2016.
- the named range dimensions/addresses haven't changed and are correct, they correspond.
- all involved named ranges are defined on workbook level

Another Example of not working code, same error

```
Public Function Save_variant_inputs(offset As Integer) As Boolean
' copy  row to primer range "varianten_in"

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Varianten").Range("varianten_in")
    .offset(offset).Value2 = .Value2
End With

Save_variant_inputs = True
End Function
```

Here is a view of the involved ranges: i dont see why this wouldnt work, can it be something with permission, sheet protection (is off on both)

[overwatch screenshot of involved ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53MpT.png)

The error occurs in all lines of type

```
Range("a").Value2 = Range("b").Value2
```

it makes no difference how the subs and functions are called (both from vba directly and via a button yields the same result)

since this code broke without me touching it i suspect the cause is located somewhere else, not related to the code itself. it has worked before

**i have added the sub to another workbook and there, it works fine.**

Comment: For **all** your ranges, specify in which worksheet your ranges are. Like: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("varianten_in")` otherwise Excel does not know in which sheet to look for the range and it might sometimes work if it guesses right and sometimes not. • You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: That does not seem to be the issue. ive updated the quesiton

Comment: Is the function `Save_variant_inputs` called by a formula in a cell or by VBA? What value did you use for `offset` and what address does the range `varianten_in` refer to? Can you add this information to the question too? • Which line exactly throws the error?

Comment: both from a button on the sheet and directly running in VBA yields same error.

Comment: the offset is not the issue, the error also occurs whithout an offset involved (first exampe)

Comment: ive added an image on the namedrange.value2 overwatch, the datatypes and size matches. and it HAS worked before, the error must be related to something completely differnt

Comment: Does it work if you set this up in an entirely fresh new workbook? I cannot get it to reproduce this error.

Comment: yes, it works fine with new ranges, even in the same workbook

Comment: That's strange, did you check the name manager if those names you use like `varianten_in` are unique? Maybe try to delete them in the name manager and re apply them. Looks like something odd went wrong here.